# Как протестировать данный класс php?

Tags: php, yii, phpunit

```
   <?php <br>
<br>
    namespace app\models;<br>
<br>
    use app\models\relations\Categories;<br>
<br>
    class MenuSite {<br>
<br>
    //отправление дерева категорий пользователю<br>
    public function getMenu() {<br>
        $categoriesList = $this->categoriesList();<br>
        $treeCategories = $this- 
       >buildingTreeOfCategories($categoriesList);
<br>
    return $treeCategories;<br>
}<br>
<br>
//получение списка категорий посредством SQL запроса<br>
private function categoriesList() {<br>
    return $categoriesList = Categories::find()<br>
->indexBy('id')<br>
->asArray()<br>
->all();<br>
}<br>
<br>
//формирование дерева с неограниченной вложенностью категорий<br>
private function buildingTreeOfCategories($categoriesList) {<br>
        $treeCategories = [];<br>
        foreach($categoriesList as $id => &$category) {<br>
    if ($category['id_parent'] === '0') {<br>
            $treeCategories[$id] = &$category;<br>
    }<br>
            $categoriesList[$category['id_parent']] ['subcategories']
                    [$category['id']] = &$category;<br>
   }<br>
      return $treeCategories;<br>
   }<br>
 }<br>
<br>
```

Добрый день. Меня интересует вопрос касательно того, каким образом правильно протестировать дынный класс.

*SQL* запрос реализован в отдельном приватном методе `categoryList`, а собственно его и хочется замокать, но при этом не хочу нарушать инкапсуляцию класса посредством модификатора `public`, ведь приватные методы не мокаются.

Есть ли какая-то возможность замокать сам класс `Categories` так, чтобы весь класс `MenuSite`, при обращении к данному классу `Categories` обращался к моку, а не к классу `Categories` непосредственно?

Или для адекватного теста мне все равно придется сделать метод `categoryList` публичным?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать магический метод `__call()`. Он вызовется, когда будет попытка обращения к недоступному методу, и можно самостоятельно построить дальнейший сценарий. Пример:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments) {
  if ($name === 'categoriesListTest') {
    return $this->categoriesList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но все равно возникает вопрос. Но ведь по сути это все равно делает класс categoryList публичным, пусть и через посредника? Что мне тогда мешает нарушить инкапсуляцию и замокать напрямую categoryList сделав его публичным? Я просто думал что есть вариант какой-то в фреймфорке phpunit анализа содержимого в методе и при напоре на определенный класс возвращать вместо него заглушку, предварительно указав, что данный класс в пределах теста будет использовать исключительно мок этого класса.

Comment: В данном случае инкапсуляция метода `categoriesList` не нарушается, добавляется метод `categoriesListTest`, но даже IDE будет его подсвечивать как несуществующий. Да, решение немного костыльное, но с `...Test` в названии запутаться будет сложнее

Comment: Спасибо. Идею понял.

Answer (score -1):

Для начала убери html теги из кода php (или тупой редактор от stackoverflow снгшный тебе так отредактировал что код стал в таком виде) 
Который раз, уже вижу - эти редакторы, модераторы входят, изменяют вопрос и все портят) Пока не уберешь brы интерпретатор не зачитает твою программу.
А обратиться к классу и использовать его методы с функциями можно вот так
$object = new Class;